# Selenium get specific text

Tags: java, selenium

It's simple, I got this html code:

```
<div id="bd" role="main">
  <p class="action-information>text1</p>
  <div id="name_id">
    <p>
      <span id = "text_id">text2</span>
      <kbd aria-labelledby="code">
        <code>CODE</code>
      </kbd>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to get the CODE text, but I don't know how exactly get there using selenium library.

Comment: I have tried all similar forms of:
String code = driver.findElement(By.id("/div[@id='name_id']")).getText(); or .getAtribute("code");

I know this would never work but these are the only kind of actions I know to extract a value.

Comment: @Roy90, well there are several things wrong with your code there. If you are truly using *that* code, you are getting an exception (I know that for sure), so you should be showing us what exception that is by pasting in the **full** error and it's stack trace.

Comment: This is just one sentence I have tried in my code to solve this. The exception, or the main error, is just that my java aplication can't find the text because I don't know how exactly refer to this <code> tag. Do you really need my whole code? Don't misunderstand me, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways, but you are just looking to get the child element of a given parent.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("name_id")).findElement(By.cssSelector("p > kbd > code")).getText();
```

or even:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#name_id > p > kbd > code")).getText();
```

The above may work (untested, may not even compile)

Comment: Both of them work perfectly. Thanks so much @Arran. Now I know an easy way to move between tags. :)